# Result of "b (None,)" on the Fibonacci sequence of Informal Introduction to Python

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am working my way through the Python's Informal Introduction, and came up against a problem in section 3.2.

This is my code:

```
>>> a,b = 0, 1  
>>> while b < 1000:  
...     print ("b"),  
...     a, b = b, a+b
```

However, instead of the printed number sequence, for a result I end up with:

```
b  
(None,)
```

repeated a number of times.  I have compared the code directly to the example given, and it seems to match.  The only problem I can think of is if the syntax changed (in another way) between the writing of the guide and the newest update of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `print(b)` not `print("b")`. The former prints the value of `b`, and the latter prints the string `"b"`.

Also, you have a comma after that print line which should be removed.

```
a,b = 0, 1  
while b < 1000: 
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a+b
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about quotations causing them to be read differently.  That solved it.

Comment: :) Yeah, anything in quotations is a string of text.

For reference, the "," after print(b) made it into a tuple (a pair of values in this case), that's what the "(None,)" bit came from. That's weird stuff, though, not anything a beginner should worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about result you are going to get, but:

print ("b"),

will print "b" as a string not as a value. To print B as value use print(b) and remove ',' at the end